# Calculating Giant Numbers using a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, fibonacci

Well, I got an assignment to build a scalable data type to use in a Fibonacci generator, and I have the assignment just about finished when I went to test it out to the 1000th number in the sequence.

I noticed that it got out of align and determined the problem to be at the 262nd number in the sequence. After a little debugging, I discovered this is where the linked list moves from 7 integers to 8 integers, but I don't know that it is related to the problem.

The number I am looking for is:

2 542 592 393 026 885 507 715 496 646 813 780 220 945 054 040 571 721 231

The number I am getting is:

1 154 259 239 326 885 507 715 496 646 813 780 220 945 054 040 571 721 231

As you may notice, they are very similar up until the last chunk (left end).

My source is a little long for SO so I made a gist:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5802620

The magic of carrying anything over 1,000,000,000 happens in the function on line 378:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5802620#file-main-cpp-L378

As an update, I am still getting 'close, but no cigar' output. Here is the code that is likely the culprit (Includes contributed answers):

```
Giant Giant::operator + (const Giant & rightSide)
{
   Giant returned;
   int extra = 0;

   for(int i = 0;
      i < chunks.getNumItems() && i < rightSide.chunks.getNumItems(); i++)
   {
      int num = chunks.getData(i) + rightSide.chunks.getData(i);
      returned.chunks.insert((num + extra) % chunkSize,
         returned.chunks.getNumItems());
      extra = (num + extra) / chunkSize;
   }

   if(chunks.getNumItems() > rightSide.chunks.getNumItems())
   {
      for(int i = rightSide.chunks.getNumItems();
          i < chunks.getNumItems(); ++i)
      {
         returned.chunks.insert(extra + chunks.getData(i),
            returned.chunks.getNumItems());
         extra = 0;
      }
   }
   else if(chunks.getNumItems() < rightSide.chunks.getNumItems())
   {
      for(int i = chunks.getNumItems();
          i < rightSide.chunks.getNumItems(); ++i)
      {
         returned.chunks.insert(extra + rightSide.chunks.getData(i),
            returned.chunks.getNumItems());
         extra = 0;
      }
   }

   if (extra != 0)
   {
       returned.chunks.insert(extra, returned.chunks.getNumItems());
   }

   return returned;
}
```

**UPDATE**
A member of the class came over and we looked through the code. Here was the problem:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const Giant & giant)
{
   for(int i = giant.chunks.getNumItems() - 1;
      i >= 0; i -= 1)
   {
      if (i != giant.chunks.getNumItems()-1)
         out << setw(9) << setfill('0');
      out << giant.chunks.getData(i);
   }
   return out;
}
```

I forgot to force display the leading zeros which caused problems. The solution has been found.

Comment: I think that would have happened long before the 292nd if that was the problem, I'm carrying anything over 1,000,000,000 so I don't overflow and int...

Comment: I hate to bring you the news, but there is a bunch of things wrong with your code: You shouldn't write your own linked list, use std::list, that one won't barf if you copy an empty list. Binary operator+ mutates the left-hand side, according to function signature (const correctness). Inserting into a list by index is O(n), that should be an array rather. Providing setNext() access to internals defies encapsulation, you could make the whole thing public. "Exception safety". Using int for booleans (bool) or the non-negative number of elements (size_t).

Comment: I would love to, but the class is called "Data Structures" and we have to implement our own Linked List, I would love to use the one in the stl. A lot of the code at the top of my source is actually my teachers that he gives to us.

Comment: You may have already noticed this, but the main difference is that your target number has a '0' before the 26, whereas your output is missing that '0'.  Other than that, the only other difference is that the target starts with '2' whereas your output starts with "11". Sorry I haven't looked at your code yet (I'm about to), but first I just thought I'd point this out in case it wasn't obvious...

Comment: Yeah, I know the problem only occurs in the 8th chunk, before that, the numbers are all correct. I would love to find that I'm accidentally `cout`-ing a 0 in a strange place.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: IMHO that's a pretty lame reason to not implement your own list. Some people prefer or have to learn *programming* and not *languages*. Anyone who's gone to school studied *implementations* of Data Structures **with** C++ and not *documentations* of Data Structures **by** C++.

Comment: Well, if you want to learn programming, then go ahead and write your own doubly-linked list (and compare it to some state-of-the-art implementation afterwards). It is more productive to base your code on a solid DLL implementation though. Also, when learning, having to debug code in multiple places doesn't make things easier, and that is an important thing to learn for general problem solving beyond programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
A member of the class came over and we looked through the code. Here was the problem:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const Giant & giant)
{
   for(int i = giant.chunks.getNumItems() - 1;
      i >= 0; i -= 1)
   {
      if (i != giant.chunks.getNumItems()-1)
         out << setw(9) << setfill('0');
      out << giant.chunks.getData(i);
   }
   return out;
}
```

I forgot to force display the leading zeros which caused problems. The solution has been found.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be on lines 387 and 389. You're not accounting `extra` soon enough in the equation. Those lines should have `((num  + extra) % chunkSize)` and `extra = (num + extra )/ chunkSize;` respectively. With your current implementation one of the segments may be 1000000000 with no carry rather than 0 with a carry (Which if I'm reading your intention if what you wanted).

Comment: After changing those lines, I am getting a strange number. 1154259239326885507715496646813780220945054040571721231 (mine) vs 2542592393026885507715496646813780220945054040571721231 (actual)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, I think you need to take `extra` into account in the loops starting on lines 399 and 408.  In particular, if extra was non-zero, and you take one of those two loops, you need to add the extra amount to the first thing you insert in that loop (as opposed to adding it separately on line 394).

**Edited as per your comment below.**  This is basically what I meant for lines 392-414:

```
if(chunks.getNumItems() > rightSide.chunks.getNumItems())
{
   for(int i = rightSide.chunks.getNumItems();
       i < chunks.getNumItems(); ++i)
   {
      returned.chunks.insert(extra + chunks.getData(i),
         returned.chunks.getNumItems());
      extra = 0;
   }
}
else if(chunks.getNumItems() < rightSide.chunks.getNumItems())
{
   for(int i = chunks.getNumItems();
       i < rightSide.chunks.getNumItems(); ++i)
   {
      returned.chunks.insert(extra + rightSide.chunks.getData(i),
         returned.chunks.getNumItems());
      extra = 0;
   }
}
else if (extra != 0)
{
    returned.chunks.insert(extra, returned.chunks.getNumItems());
}
```

Of course, if that works, there are ways to "streamline it" too.

Comment: I tried that and got an extremely large number. I'm wondering if there is a better way to carry the extra?

Comment: @Ryan_Alfred I just edited my response to show what I meant with code, just in case if wasn't clear.  Note that my code there includes replacing the if-block on lines 392-395 as well.

Comment: @RyanAllred (sorry about your name -- my eyes aren't so good.)  What is the output now?